# My default user login table is 'login' in laravel10 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am new learner to Laravel bellow the details of problem.

Laravel-10 default user login table is `users` but I have changed another user login table and my table name like  'logins'.

I have also change made in `app\model\User.php` like `protected $table = 'logins';`

Here is error:

> [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it SELECT   * FROM   logins WHERE   email = @ gmail.com' limit
> 1

Could you please resolve this.

Comment: Recheck your .env file and ensure you have configured DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_CONNECTION, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, and DB_PASSWORD.

Comment: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` means that you cannot connect to the database. Either the information is wrong, or there's a firewall preventing the connection.